# CSV date into arraylist_Java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNXqs.png)

I am trying to save data separately by using ArrayList.
However, after saving one data into the array, it skips one line then saves the data. Please help me with this problem.

```
private void readCSVFile(String tickerCode, File file) {
    System.out.println("Reading file " + tickerCode);
    System.out.println(file.getPath());
    try {
        ArrayList<List<String>> line = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        CSVReaderHeaderAware csvReader = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(br);
        int numLine = 0;
        String[] values;
        while ((values = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            data.add(values[0]);
            data.add(values[1]);
            data.add(values[2]);
            data.add(values[3]);
            data.add(values[4]);
            data.add(values[5]);
            data.add(values[6]);
            line.add(data);

            if(numLine == 0){
                System.out.print("StartDate = "+ values[0]);
            }
            if((csvReader.readNext() == null)){
                System.out.println(" EndDate = " + values[0]);
            }
            ++numLine;
        }
```

[debugger variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Lva.jpg)

Comment: I do not think you should be doing `if((csvReader.readNext() == null)){` - `readNext` does actual read the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you cannot use `csvReader.readNext()` inside the loop as well to check if the next element is `null`, because it will actually read the next line. So what you can do is keep the last processed row's date in a variable, and then print it as the EndDate after the while loop is finished.

```
ArrayList<List<String>> line = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
CSVReaderHeaderAware csvReader = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(br);
int numLine = 0;
String[] values;
String endDate = null;
while ((values = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(values[0]);
    data.add(values[1]);
    data.add(values[2]);
    data.add(values[3]);
    data.add(values[4]);
    data.add(values[5]);
    data.add(values[6]);
    line.add(data);

    if(numLine == 0){
        System.out.print("StartDate = "+ values[0]);
    }
    endDate = values[0];
    ++numLine;
}

if (endDate != null) { // Need to check null in case your CSV didn't have any rows
    System.out.println(" EndDate = " + endDate);
}
```